# Using css in HTMLEditor and TextArea JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm creating a textarea and an htmleditor using SceneBuilder, so when I run the project it appears without styling, searching the javafx css guide it doesn't show how to style an htmleditor.

I have two questions:

1. How to style an HTMLEditor?
2. Pressing the right mouse button inside the HTMLEditor and the TextArea shows the options to copy, paste, cut and others, but without styling. How can I style that option box?

HTMLEditor:

[image]

HTMLEditor copiar,pegar.. :

[image]

TextArea copiar,pegar... :

[image]

Comment: What do you want to style, the editor itself including the controls in the editor ribbon, or the HTML content in the editor?

Comment: I want to give css style to the options box (copy, paste, cut...) of the HTMLEditor and the TextArea.